# Using All Interrupt Vector Of A Timer

Tags: arduino, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

## Purpose

I'm doing some timer experiment on atmega328.
I'm attempting to use every interrupt (except OVF).
Trying to make timer1 act likes 3 individual timers.
This might comes in handy when ran out of timer.

According to manual,there are 4 interrupt vectors related to timer1.

> [image: timer1 interrupts]
>   Timer1 Interrupt Vectors

My idea is making TCNT1 keep counting from 0 to 65535.
Then set the desired compare value in OCR1A,OCR1B and ICR1 registers.
When interrupts, manually add value to registers, so next interrupt will be trigger in same duration.

I wrote some codes to verify and the result seems to be ideal.

I'm considering that is this a proper way to use a timer? 
or this may cause some bugs,error or efficiency issue?

Thanks!

---

## Codes

```c
int A_Ticks   = 15624;     //64us*(15624+1) = 1000ms
int B_Ticks   = 23436;     //1500ms
int ICR_Ticks = 31248;     //2000ms

void setup()
{   
    Serial.begin(115200);

    TCCR1A = 0x00;               
    TCCR1B = 0x00;        

    TCCR1B|= _BV(WGM13);          //enable TIMER1_CAPT_vect
    TCCR1B|= _BV(WGM12);          //enable CTC

    TCCR1B |= _BV(CS12);          //prescaler = CPU clock/1024
    TCCR1B &= ~_BV(CS11);         //per tick = 64us
    TCCR1B |= _BV(CS10);    

    OCR1A = A_Ticks; 
    OCR1B = B_Ticks;
    ICR1  = ICR_Ticks;

    char oldSREG = SREG;
    noInterrupts();
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);         // enable timer interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1B);         
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(ICIE1); 
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(TOIE1); 
    TCNT1=0;    
    SREG = oldSREG;     
}

void loop()
{
    delay(100);
}

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{ 
  Serial.print(millis());   
  Serial.println(":COMPA");
  OCR1A+=A_Ticks;            //add value manually
}

ISR (TIMER1_COMPB_vect)
{   
  Serial.print(millis());
  Serial.println(":COMPB");
  OCR1B+=B_Ticks;            //add value manually
}

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.println(":OVF_vect");
}

ISR (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    //When interrupt into TIMER1_CAPT_vect 
    //TCNT will be clear to 0 due to CTC is on
    //manually set it to value of ICR1 to make TCNT keep counting

    TCNT1=ICR1;
    ICR1+=ICR_Ticks;            //add value manually

    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.println(":CAPT_vect");
}
```

---

## Result

```
999:COMPA
1499:COMPB
1999:CAPT_vect
1999:COMPA
2999:COMPA
2999:COMPB
3999:CAPT_vect
3999:COMPA
4194:OVF_vect
4499:COMPB
4999:COMPA
5999:CAPT_vect
5999:COMPA
5999:COMPB
6999:COMPA
7498:COMPB
7999:CAPT_vect
7999:COMPA
8388:OVF_vect
```

Comment: This type of question would be better suited for https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, you can use a single timer this way to generate multiple frequencies.  Here is a [TI App Note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa513a/slaa513a.pdf) that describes the technique.  I haven't reviewed your implementation for bugs though.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance,I'll look into the document and website.

Comment: Just be careful how long your ISR takes to execute. If too long and called frequently they can ate all CPU time and even "overlap" leading, then to bugs / unexecpted behaviour. Better set a flag, or increment a counter and return immediatly. Then print message in main loop and reset flag/decrease counter